# How to open Lightning carousel image href record detail

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Folks!

i have a LWC Carousel with 5 images on it, but when i click the picture, it doesn't redirect to the record details, it seems like i need to add some extra logic in the href section, what i have missing on my code?.

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Próximas Campañas" icon-name="custom:custom11">
    <div class="slds-box_x-small slds-m-around_small">
                <lightning-carousel>
                    <template for:each={campaigns.data} for:item="campaign">
                        <lightning-carousel-image key={campaign.id}
                            src = {campaign.ruta_imagen__c}
                            header = {campaign.Name}
                            description = {campaign.Description}
                            alternative-text = {campaign.Name}
                            href = {campaign.id}>
                        </lightning-carousel-image>
                    </template>   
                </lightning-carousel>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getLastCampaign from '@salesforce/apex/featuredCampaignClass.getLastCampaigns';


export default class FeaturedCampaign extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getLastCampaign) campaigns;
    
}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class featuredCampaignClass {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Campaign>  getLastCampaigns() {
    return  [SELECT Id, Name, ruta_imagen__c, Description FROM Campaign Order By StartDate asc LIMIT 5];
}}
```

i have tried some solutions with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the ID is indeed not enough. You need to add a leading `/`. You can do this with a custom wire handler:

```
campaigns;
campaignLoadError;
@wire(getLastCampaign) campaignsWireHandler({data,error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.campaigns = data.map(value=>({...value,campaignUrl:`/${value.id}`}));
    this.campaignLoadError = null;
  }
  if(error) {
    this.campaigns = null;
    this.campaignLoadError = error;
  }
}
```

I'll explain each part in detail:

```
data // Incoming result from the wire call
.map( // Perform translation with Array.map
  value=> // Map callback function parameter is object for each array index
  ({ ...value, // Makes a writeable copy that includes all existing properties
    campaignUrl: `/${value.id}` // Given a campaign ID, assign a / in front of it
  }) // Note: parentheses on both sides convert this to an Object instead of Function.
);
```

Then, you just update the markup accordingly:

```
href = {campaign.campaignUrl}>
```

Comment: Thanks!, it work flawless, i need to understand better the wire settings, so i will made myself a study guide :)

Answer (score 0):

I let the HTML here, the 'data' tag is not necesary after the solution.

```
<lightning-card title="Próximas Campañas" icon-name="custom:custom11">
    <div class="slds-box_x-small slds-m-around_small">
                <lightning-carousel>
                    <template for:each={campaigns} for:item="campaign">
                        <lightning-carousel-image key={campaign.id}
                            src = {campaign.ruta_imagen__c}
                            header = {campaign.Name}
                            description = {campaign.Description}
                            alternative-text = {campaign.Name}
                            href = {campaign.campaignUrl}>
                        </lightning-carousel-image>
                    </template>   
                </lightning-carousel>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```